# Parse JSON string with Python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, parsing

I've got such string from JSON request:

```
[{"foo": "100100000024635"}]
```

here are the request:

```
list = json.dumps(bar.json()['result'])
```

and I can't get it by `list['foo']`

Comment: `json.dumps` returns a json-encoded string. Did you mean to do `json.loads`? And please post a working example. "I've got such string..." is very unclear ...  you show us some magical `bar.json()` function without telling us whether it returns json-encoded data or json-decoded data... and it doesn't match the example you have us in the first place!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you get in the response is a list of dictionaries.

iterate the list and then read the value for key 'foo'

```
for obj in list:
    print obj['foo']
```

Comment: @Anbarasan already tried
(`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 46, in <module>
    print obj['foo']
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str`)

Comment: @sem1993 you are trying to use list['foo'] inside the loop.  try using obj['foo']

Comment: @Anbarasan corrected my comment, I'm using `obj['foo']`

Comment: The error says that obj in a list and not dictionary.  @sem1993 are you sure that `list variable has a list of dictionaries as you mentioned in the question, or is it something else?

Comment: @Anbarasan that's all data which is stored in `list` variable after successful request: `[{"foo": "100100000024635"}]`

Comment: In the question, they use `json.dumps`. This produces a string representation of the JSON. (list is a string)- to parse it into dictionaries, use `json.loads` instead. That standardizes it into Python variables.